# Renaming parts of files with Windows Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-rename

How could i rename a certain part of all files inside a directory.

Example

```
[HorribleSubs] File1 [720p].mkv
[HorribleSubs] File2 [1080p].mkv
```

Must be renamed into

```
File1.mkv
File2.mkv
```

Comment: **Similar:** [Batch script to remove parts of a filename](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19148942/1497596)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "tokens=2delims=[]" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\[*]*[*].mkv" '
 ) DO (
 SET "newname=%%a"
 ECHO(REN "%sourcedir%\[*]%%a[*].mkv" "!newname:~1,-1!.mkv"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

This should fix your problem.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple batch you can use to rename a single file manually.

```
@echo off
title Rename Bat
echo This bat must be in the folder that 
echo contains the files to be renamed.
echo Enter File Name
set /p old=
echo Enter New Name
set /p new=
ren "%old%" "%new%"
echo Done
pause
```

this has a loop to do multiple files manually

```
@echo off
title Rename Bat
echo This bat must be in the folder that 
echo contains the files to be renamed.
:begin
echo Enter File Name
set /p old=
echo Enter New Name
set /p new=
ren "%old%" "%new%"
echo Done
ping -n 3 127.0.0.1 >NUL
goto begin
```

its real simple hope it helps. fyi it works on windows XP

Answer (score 0):

place file In directory you wanna rename

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

dir /b ¦ find /v /c "*">filescount.txt

for /f %%f in (filescount.txt) do (
    set /a "nof=%%f-2" 

    for /L %%n in (1 1 !nof!) do (
        for %%a in (*.mkv) do (
            rename "%%a" "file%%n%%~xa"
        )
    )
)
```